# How can I boot Ubuntu again after installing Windows 8 Developer Preview?

Tags: ubuntu, grub, multi-boot, windows-8-preview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Triple booting Windows 8 Consumer Preview with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.10](https://superuser.com/questions/396467/triple-booting-windows-8-consumer-preview-with-windows-7-and-ubuntu-11-10)

I installed WDP on a disk where Ubuntu was already present. Now the Ubuntu partition is still present, but when I start my computer I do not get the choice: the bootloader of Windows has replaced GRUB.

Is there a safe way to re-enable GRUB so that I can select either Windows or Ubuntu at boot time?

Comment: I reinstalled GRUB but it broke my Windows install. It remains stuck at the Loading screen. Will post an answer if I figure it out.

Comment: @Capt.Nemo Thank you for the warning... Good luck! I will wait for your answer.

Comment: Take a look at this post - one of the answers tells you what to do: http://superuser.com/questions/396467/triple-booting-windows-8-consumer-preview-with-windows-7-and-ubuntu-11-10

Answer (score 2):

If you do not happen to know how grub works, try [Super Grub Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/).

Comment: I have already used SGD in the past for another task. Are you sure it will work without breaking my Windows install? I need to be sure before trying!

Comment: @Luc1245 Grub is a nice bootloader that accepts that you might have multiple OSs. Window's bootloader is not so nice. You do have to reinstate Grub. It's not even touching the windows install, or the windows bootloader, just putting itself back as the first logical partition run.